# How to fix "unhashable type: 'list'" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to run a function to get column name corresponding to 2 in data frame

Input Dataframe:

df1

```
A|B|C|D

1|0|2|4

2|9|1|3
```

Output DataFrame:

```
A|B|C|D|new|

1|0|2|4|C|

2|9|1|3|A|
```

I have made the function but for some reason I am getting TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index 0')

```
def colname(x):
    b = (df1.loc[x]==2)
    return b.idxmax()
```

```
df1["new"]=df1.apply(colname,axis=1)
```

Comment: `df['new'] = df.eq(2).idxmax(1)`

Comment: That worked, Thanks